# Getting Combobox.Value in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have this code:

```
If Me.Combobox.Value = "My Text" Then
```

As I want to test if "My Text" is the only value selected, however, the conditional is skipped.

I have also tried

```
Me.Combobox.Column(1)
```

and

```
Me.Combobox.Text
```

I believe there is some simple solution that I'm just overlooking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Me.Combobox.Column(1)` decided to work as I retested the possibilities.